# Getting Firebase Reg Token in Unreal Engine 4

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, token, unreal-engine4, remote-notifications

I was wondering where to find / how to get the Requested Firebase Token?? I am trying to recive remote messages by using FCM, since its build in the engine.

Any idea how to get this working?
[here an image about the plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12yxD.png)